# Why isn't a notification generated javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

This is my code

`var notification = new Notification('notify');`

Do I have to invoke the *notification* or should this be enough? I have also tried the code on the mdn website which is.

```
    Notification.requestPermission();
    // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
      alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }
  
    // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
      // If it's okay let's create a notification
      console.log("granted")
      var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");


    }
  
    // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
    else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
        console.log("denied")
      Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
        // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
        if (permission === "granted") {
          var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
        }
      });
    }

  
    // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you
    // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
  }
```

The function is called and the word "granted" is logged so it seems like we permissions but for some reason I see no notification either on chrome or safari? I am using local host. Why am I not seeing a notification?

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you provided works fine on my Chrome, you can test it in an online editor if you have any doubts.

Here you can try an example, i just scraped https://js.do/code/552731 with your sample.

Does it work here ?

I'm not sure the issue is related with the code sample you provided.

EDIT: After checking, it might be related to https/http issues, you might want to look into this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960501/web-notifications-is-not-working-on-chrome-but-its-working-fine-on-firefox-and)